# Form cant progress any further and seems on getting stuck in function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

when checking one of the language,degree or car options and fill out their corresponding inputs the form gets gets stuck on the Cage() function(it displays the message but doesnt progress further) and I dont know why any clues?I also find out by removing the upper functions (Cemail,Cuser,Checkpassword) one by one that they all get stuck and don't let the button get enabled.Is it because too many boolean functions are in the enableMe() if?
I am a student and still learning so, sorry for the headache in advance.

```js
function Cuser() {
    var Us = document.getElementById("User").value;
    if (Us.length < 7 || Us.length > 15) {
        l1.innerHTML = "The username must be at least 7 characters and up to 15";
        return false;
    }
    else if (Us == "" || Us == " " || Us == "  " || Us == "   " || Us == null) {
        l1.innerHTML = "The username must be filled with at least 7 characters";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        l1.innerHTML = "Username is Valid";
        return true
    }
}
function Cemail() {
    var Em = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    var patt = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (Em == "" || Em == " " || Em == "  " || Em == "   " || Em == null) {
        l1.innerHTML = "Please fill out the email";
        return false;
    }
    else if (!patt.test(Em)) {
        l1.innerHTML = "Please fill out the email correctly";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        l1.innerHTML = "email is valid";
        return true;
    }
}
function CheckPassword() {
    var p = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    var p1 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    var pattent = /[A-Z]/;
    if (p == "" || p == " " || p == "  " || p == "   " || p == null) {
        l1.innerHTML = "The password must be filled with at least 6 characters";
        return false;
    }
    else if (p.length < 6 || p1.length > 12) {
        l1.innerHTML = "Password min chars:6 Max chars:12";
        return false;
    }
    else if (!p.match(pattent)) {
        l1.innerHTML = "please include at least one capital letter"
    return false;
    }
    else if (p1 != p) {
        l1.innerHTML = "Passwords must be identical.";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        l1.innerHTML = "password is valid";
        return true;
    }

}
function checkPasswordStrenght() {
    var x = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    if (x.length == 6) {
        document.getElementById("strenght").value = "0";
    }

    if (x.length == 7) {
        document.getElementById("strenght").value = "15";

    }
    if (x.length == 8) {
        document.getElementById("strenght").value = "30";
    }
    if (x.length == 9) {
        document.getElementById("strenght").value = "45";

    }
    if (x.length == 10) {
        document.getElementById("strenght").value = "65";

    }
    if (x.length == 11) {
        document.getElementById("strenght").value = "80";
    }
    if (x.length == 12) {
        document.getElementById("strenght").value = "100";
    }
}
function Cage() {
    var Ag = document.getElementById("Age").value;
    if (isNaN(Ag) == true || Ag == "  " || Ag == "" || Ag == " ") {
        l1.innerHTML = "Age must be a number.";
        return false;
    }
    else if (Ag < 18) {
            l1.innerHTML = "You must be an Adult to use this form";
        return false;

    }
    else {
        l1.innerHTML = "Age is valid";
        return true;
    }
}

function DisableMe() {
    document.getElementById("butt").disabled = true;
}

function myCar() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function myDegree() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myDeg");
    var text = document.getElementById("Ddeg");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function myLangu() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myLang");
    var text = document.getElementById("Llang");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function Checker() {
  

    if (document.getElementById("GF").checked == false && document.getElementById("GM").checked == false) {
        l1.innerHTML = "Please select your gender";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
    
function CChecker() {
    var Cheddar = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
    var Ham = document.getElementById("TypeOfCar").value;
    if (Cheddar == true) {
        if (Ham == "" || Ham == " " || Ham == "  " || Ham == "   " || Ham == null) {
            l1.innerHTML = "Please Fill in the type of car you own";
           
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
function LChecker() {
    var Lettuce = document.getElementById("myLang").checked;
    var Tomato = document.getElementById("TypeOfLang").value;
    if (Lettuce == true) {
        if (Tomato == "" || Tomato == " " || Tomato == "  " || Tomato == "   " || Tomato == null) {
            l1.innerHTML = "Please Fill in at least one foreign language that you know";
           
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
function DChecker() {
    var Bread = document.getElementById("myDeg").checked;
    var Mayo = document.getElementById("TypeOfDeg").value;
    if (Bread == true) {
        if (Mayo == "" || Mayo == " " || Mayo == "  " || Mayo == "   " || Mayo == null) {
            l1.innerHTML = "Please Fill in at least one degree you own";
            
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function enableMe() {
    if (Cuser() && Cemail && CheckPassword && Cage() && Checker() && CChecker() && LChecker() && DChecker()) {
        document.getElementById("butt").disabled = false;
        l1.innerHTML = "All credentials are valid";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("butt").disabled = true;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="Form signup and php">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Signup,html,php,react">
    <meta name="author" content="Filippos Karagiannis">
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Exclusive Signup</title>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue; text-align:center;" onload="DisableMe()">

    <center>
        <form action="react.html" display: inline - block;">


            <fieldset class="center" style="width:50%; font-size:x-large; color:#383838;font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif">

                <legend><b>Sign up form</b></legend>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" id="User" name="Username" onchange="return Cuser()" placeholder="Type Username" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input type="email" id="mail" name="Email" onchange="return Cemail()" placeholder="e-Mail" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="password" id="pass1" name="Pass1"
                           placeholder="Password" onkeyup="checkPasswordStrenght(pass1), CheckPassword()" />
                    <input type="password" id="pass2" name="Pass2"
                           placeholder="Confirm Password" />


                </p>
                <div class="Strng">Password strenght:</div> <progress max="100" value="0" id="strenght" style="width:230px"></progress>
                <p> <input type="text" id="Age" onchange="return Cage()" name="Age" placeholder="Type Age" /> </p>

                <div class="Strng">
                    Male<input type="radio" id="GM" name="gender" value="male">
                    <input type="radio" id="GF" name="gender" value="female"> Female
                </div>
                <div class=" Strng">Do you own a car?<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myCar()"></div>
                <div id="text" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="TypeOfCar" placeholder="Please inlcude the type of car" /></div>

                <div class=" Strng">Do you know any other Languages<input type="checkbox" id="myLang" onclick="myLangu()"></div>
                <div id="Llang" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="TypeOfLang" placeholder="Please inlcude the Languages" /></div>

                <div class=" Strng">Do you own any postgraduate degrees<input type="checkbox" id="myDeg" onclick="myDegree()"></div>
                <div id="Ddeg" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="TypeOfDeg" placeholder="Please inlcude the type of Degrees" /></div>
 

                <p><div onmouseover="return enableMe()">Click Bellow to register your credentials</div></p>
          
                    <div onmouseover="return enableMe()">
                        <input class="button" id="butt" type="submit" value="Register">
                    </div>
      
                <label class="Labbel" id="l1"></label>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (Cuser() && Cemail && CheckPassword && Cage() ... )` did you forget the parenthesis for Cemail and CheckPassword?

Comment: Also `<form action="react.html" display: inline - block;">` should be `<form action="react.html" style="display: inline-block;">`

Comment: indeed i did forget to call the functions correctly but that was a mistake I made while I was trying to resolve the problem(i was removing the functions one by one to see which one is faulty) I seemed to have copied that little mistake.Problem still persists though :/

Comment: Also, just a note: You should use the [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to check for whiteapace-only input. So, `Us.trim() == ""` instead of `Us == "" || Us == " " || Us == "     " ... `

Comment: Thanks for the input! This really makes my code more pretty to look at and just more practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as some syntax errors Burham mentions in the comments.

Why the button won't enable is due to your `CChecker()`, `LChecker()` and `DChecker()` functions, you never return true if one is selected and a value is filled.

Example of where to add return (view comment, add to other functions in same place):

```
function CChecker() {
    var Cheddar = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
    var Ham = document.getElementById("TypeOfCar").value;
    if (Cheddar == true) {
        if (Ham == "" || Ham == " " || Ham == "  " || Ham == "   " || Ham == null) {
            l1.innerHTML = "Please Fill in the type of car you own";

        }
        // else return true
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeap, that fixed it. I really thought the problem would be more complex than 3 unfinished identical ifs'.Thanks for pointing out the problem and solving it at the same time!